# Elasticsearch cluster ClusterStatsCollector timed out

Tags: elasticsearch

My elasticserach cluster went down when I was trying to create index pattern in Kibana. None of the cat API's are working eg. _cat/nodes

In elastic master node logs I can see:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [data-3-vm-zone-1227643n][xx.xx.133.151:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/stats[n]] request_id [9651533] timed out after [15000ms]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:908) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        ... 4 more
[2017-02-15T06:38:40,046][ERROR][o.e.x.m.c.i.IndexRecoveryCollector] [master1-vm-zone-p1227651n] collector [index-recovery-collector] timed out when collecting data
[2017-02-15T06:38:50,047][ERROR][o.e.x.m.c.i.IndexStatsCollector] [master1-vm-zone-p1227651n] collector [index-stats-collector] timed out when collecting data
[2017-02-15T06:39:00,048][ERROR][o.e.x.m.c.i.IndicesStatsCollector] [master1-vm-zone-p1227651n] collector [indices-stats-collector] timed out when collecting data
[2017-02-15T06:39:10,048][ERROR][o.e.x.m.c.c.ClusterStatsCollector] [master1-vm-zone-p1227651n] collector [cluster-stats-collector] timed out when collecting data
[2017-02-15T06:39:30,152][ERROR][o.e.x.m.c.i.IndexRecoveryCollector] [master1-vm-zone-p1227651n] collector [index-recovery-collector] timed out when collecting data
[2017-02-15T06:39:31,884][DEBUG][o.e.a.a.c.n.s.TransportNodesStatsAction] [master1-vm-zone-p1227651n] failed to execute on node [FN8JwM_rS7WgSP0h9hXvMA]
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [data-3-vm-zone-p1227643n][xx.xx.133.151:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/stats[n]] request_id [9651829] timed out after [15000ms]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:908) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:527) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
[2017-02-15T06:39:31,884][DEBUG][o.e.a.a.c.n.s.TransportNodesStatsAction] [master1-vm-zone-p1227651n] failed to execute on node [yyaGz1WWQyyQXmstHpKSbw]
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [data-2-vm-zone-p1227642n][xx.xx.133.150:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/stats[n]] request_id [9651827] timed out after [15000ms]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:908) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:527) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
[2017-02-15T06:39:31,884][DEBUG][o.e.a.a.c.n.s.TransportNodesStatsAction] [master1-vm-zone-p1227651n] failed to execute on node [DEw888fjSMm0ODb3D7nMPg]
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [data-1-vm-zone-p1227641n][xx.xx.133.149:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/stats[n]] request_id [9651828] timed out after [15000ms]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:908) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:527) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
[2017-02-15T06:39:31,885][WARN ][o.e.a.a.c.n.s.TransportNodesStatsAction] [master1-vm-zone-p1227651n] not accumulating exceptions, excluding exception from response
org.elasticsearch.action.FailedNodeException: Failed node [yyaGz1WWQyyQXmstHpKSbw]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.onFailure(TransportNodesAction.java:247) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.access$300(TransportNodesAction.java:160) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction$1.handleException(TransportNodesAction.java:219) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1024) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:907) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:527) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [data-2-vm-zone-p1227642n][xx.xx.133.150:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/stats[n]] request_id [9651827] timed out after [15000ms]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:908) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        ... 4 more
[2017-02-15T06:39:31,886][WARN ][o.e.a.a.c.n.s.TransportNodesStatsAction] [master1-vm-zone-p1227651n] not accumulating exceptions, excluding exception from response
org.elasticsearch.action.FailedNodeException: Failed node [DEw888fjSMm0ODb3D7nMPg]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.onFailure(TransportNodesAction.java:247) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.access$300(TransportNodesAction.java:160) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction$1.handleException(TransportNodesAction.java:219) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1024) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:907) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:527) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [data-1-vm-zone-p1227641n][xx.xx.133.149:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/stats[n]] request_id [9651828] timed out after [15000ms]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:908) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        ... 4 more
[2017-02-15T06:39:31,886][WARN ][o.e.a.a.c.n.s.TransportNodesStatsAction] [master1-vm-zone-p1227651n] not accumulating exceptions, excluding exception from response
org.elasticsearch.action.FailedNodeException: Failed node [FN8JwM_rS7WgSP0h9hXvMA]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.onFailure(TransportNodesAction.java:247) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.access$300(TransportNodesAction.java:160) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction$1.handleException(TransportNodesAction.java:219) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1024) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:907) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:527) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [data-3-vm-zone-p1227643n][xx.xx.133.151:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/stats[n]] request_id [9651829] timed out after [15000ms]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:908) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
        ... 4 more
```

Any Idea what might went wrong?

Comment: Same issue here. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

To control how data is collected from your Elasticsearch nodes, you configure xpack.monitoring.collection settings in elasticsearch.yml. Check the file elasticsearch.yml and if it (15000ms in your case) is over the time limtation (10000ms), then it will time out.

Reference: [Monitoring Settings in Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/5.5/monitoring-settings-kb.html#monitoring-settings-kb)